# Attach edge without existing verts

Tags: modeling, vertices, extrude

I'm new to blender, and I've created a bunch of disconnected geometry to practice building clean topology.  I'm just wondering, what's the best way of tackling this problem?

[image]

The highlighted edge has been extruded, and needs to be connected to the edge on the left, however there aren't any verts there, so it would just float.

What's the best way to connect these two pieces together?  I could go ahead and cut in the verts first, then extrude.  I was just hoping there is a method for automatically inserting the verts on the left hand edge?

Apologies if this has already been asked, it's sometimes difficult to articulate the problem!

Comment: I don't thing there is a general good answer to this question. You can either add vertices on the left part, but you can also connect with the vertex visible on the upper left of the image. In fact, the image is too close up and I think having a more global vision of it (and knowing what the mesh is to be) is needed to make a decision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated my lemon, there are numerous ways and you need to consider the flow of the topology. Nevertheless, here is the most basic method.

1. Hover over the edges to the left and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to [loop cut](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/loop_subdivide.html#loop-cut-and-slide). A purple line will appear during this operation, scrolling the mouse wheel controls the amount of added edge loops. I scrolled once. Confirm with <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>.
2. <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> Select the vertices respectively and make a face with <kbd>F</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Leander and Lemon, this is what I suspected.  Just wanted to know if there was any kind of existing tool/plugin that would create verts on existing geometry if there was something floating on top of it.  Thanks.